# Mysql: Join Table Only First row on left table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The query is

```
SELECT * FROM Question 
INNER JOIN Question_Answer 
  ON Question.question_id = Question_Answer.question_id 
WHERE Question.question_group_id = 518
```

**Question Table has the following columns:**

```
question_id|question_name|question_type|question_group_id|question_ask
1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1
2          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question2
3          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question3
4          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question4
```

**Question_Answer has the following columns:**

```
question_id|question_answer_text|question_answer_id|question_answer_is_correct
518           |Text1                    |1107                  |1
518           |Text2                    |1108                  |1
518           |Text3                    |1109                  |1
518           |Text4                    |1110                  |1
```

**The Problem is that it outputs something like this:**

```
question_id|question_name|question_type|question_group_id|question_ask|question_id|question_answer_text|question_answer_id|question_answer_is_correct

1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1 | 518           |Text1                    |1107                  |1
1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1 | 518           |Text2                    |1108                  |1
1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1 | 518           |Text3                    |1109                  |1
1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1 | 518           |Text4                    |1110                  |1
```

**What I want to achieve is this:**

```
1          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question1 | 518           |Text1                    |1107                  |1
2          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question2 | 518           |Text2                    |1108                  |1
3          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question3 | 518           |Text3                    |1109                  |1
4          |100-105      | gr           | 518                | question4 | 518           |Text4                    |1110                  |1
```

Comment: Your data's messed up then.  Quesiton.Question_ID is {1,2,3,4}  Question_answer Question_ID is only {518}.  518 will never equal {1,2,3,4}.  I'm surprised you get any data with that query.  Perhaps you mean to join on `Question.question_group_Id to Question_Answer.Question_ID` though that too will result in too many associations.  so you'd have to have something in the answer table refer back to the question_id in question table... yep... I think bad data in answer table....  Specifically in question_Id column

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I didn't notice that. It is indeed a mess up in the data. I am not sure where the bug is rooted from though.

The thing is, question_id in Question_Answer should have been 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively. Some bug in the program changed it to the same id which is the question_group_id from the Question table. That is something I have to trace.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if something stops working and code didn't change look at the data first. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the data, or fix your join.

**Your join is:** 
Question.question_id = Question_Answer.question_id

**However the data is:** {1,2,3,4} <> {518}

Either the join is wrong, or the data is.